# Adding one to a vector

Tags: vector, increment

I am trying to translate c code into MATLAB, and I have come across some code that I don't understand. Specifically, there is a variable defined as:

```
static float *lpfdata;
```

This gets assigned during a function call to:

```
envelope_old(&fdata[0], lpfdata, winlength, samprate, BW);
```

Which accepts input as:

```
void envelope_old (float *fdata, float *lpfdata, int nsamps, int samprate,
```

float cutoff)

Within envelope_old, lpfdata is referenced as a vector, being assigned values in a loop in the format "`lpfdata[i] = ...`" where i is the index variable in the loop.

Later, a function call in the format:

```
downsample( lpfdata+1, dwndata, winlength, downby);
```

is called. What does the +1 mean in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a pointer, `lpfdata[n]` and `lpfdata+n` are the same - they both add `n * sizeof(*lpfdata)` to the raw pointer and access the memory at that address.

In this case, `lpfdata` points to elements of type `float`, so `sizeof(*lpfdata) == sizeof(float)`